# How to prevent GCP Vertex losing logs from my docker run?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-logging

I am training a Tensorflow 2 model on Google Cloud Platform using the Vertex AI service. I build a docker image, upload it to Container Registry, then run it on Vertex.

Vertex automatically submits the output to Cloud Logging. Unfortunately it frequently loses some of the output. It seems to most often lose the output if the total output is short, or at the end of the output stream. It also seems that different log levels are treated differently, so for example level INFO might be collected but level WARNING lost. When I run the image locally I get everything.

It seems I can make the logs come through by dumping out a lot of extra output. I don't really want to do this for every log level. I tried various things to flush the logs which are shown in my script.

Is anyone aware of this or know why it is happening?

Some recreation test scripts are below for completeness.

Update: I tested the image on Google Cloud Run and the logs are collected correctly there (I still have to use Vertex though).

---

`script.py`

```
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
print('Test message')
logging.info("Info message")
logging.warning("Warning message")
print('Flushing print buffer.', flush=True)
logging.shutdown()
time.sleep(3.)
```

---

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
WORKDIR /root

RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -nv \
    https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && \
    mkdir /root/tools && \
    tar xvzf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz -C /root/tools && \
    rm google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && \
    /root/tools/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=false \
        --path-update=false --bash-completion=false \
        --disable-installation-options && \
    rm -rf /root/.config/* && \
    ln -s /root/.config /config && \
    # Remove the backup directory that gcloud creates
    rm -rf /root/tools/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup \
ENV PATH $PATH:/root/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin
RUN echo '[GoogleCompute]\nservice_account = default' > /etc/boto.cfg

COPY script.py /root/script.py
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "script.py"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting us know of the issue and for providing a reproducible example. We are investigating the issue in Vertex AI and will follow up when we have some more details.

Comment: Hi rpasricha, thank you.